# A formula that does Excel "countifs" function involving dates

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have a Google spreadsheet in which multiple users are tracking a list of dates and class names (math, reading, writing, etc). On a separate sheet in the same document, I want to be able to give a count of how many times each class name shows up within a particular date range. Here is a sample workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlMRSUls9YJDdEZqeU9VaFJCbDJOZlpkRG0zcktHYnc

To rephrase the question: on the page `stats` in columns E:J I want to count how many times the classes listed in Row 4 are showing up in Column E of the sheet `summer` between the dates listed. For example, in `stats` cell E6, I want to know how many times a user entered Math on the sheet `summer` in the period July 9-13.

In Excel I would do this with the countifs function, but that doesn't work in Google Sheets.

Does anyone know about a work-around I could use in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

As of 11-12-2013 the `COUNTIFS` function is available in the new Google Sheets:

- https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3256550

See following reference, on how to activate the new Google Sheets:

- https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DCOUNT Function.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel "COUNTIFS" function in Google spreadsheets.

Check this Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum((A27:A5025="Man")*(C27:C5025="Yes")))
```